Terraform: How do I call the values of lists of strings from Input variable in locals variables specific to "azurerm_storage_management_policy"
I am trying to assign Storage account lifecycle management policy using terraform. The lists of more than 30 containers are defined in the input.tfvars file as lists of strings which needs to be called in main.tf in "resource azurerm_storage_management_policy lifecycle". But it is giving error. Please guide how should I call the variable.
The code details in my git is given below.
input.tfvars -
containername = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g".................................]

This list includes more than 30 container names.
variables.tf ---
variable "containername" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = []
}

main.tf --
locals {
   folderlist1  = var.containername
   list1 = [ for a in local.folderlist1: a ]
 }
 output "result1" {
     value = local.list1
}
resource "azurerm_storage_management_policy" "lifecycle" {
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.sa.id
  rule{
    name    = "Rule1"
    enabled = true
    filters {
      prefix_match = local.list1
      blob_types   = ["blockBlob"] 
    }
    actions {
      base_blob {
        delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 15
      }
      snapshot {
        delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = 15
      }
    }
  }
}

Giving error as "prefix_match": element 0: string required.

For this to work, you would need to use the dynamic block with for_each meta-argument:
locals {
  folderlist1  = var.containername
  list1 = [ for a in local.folderlist1: a ]
}

output "result1" {
  value = local.folderlist1
}

resource "azurerm_storage_management_policy" "lifecycle" {
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.sa.id
  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = local.folderlist1
    content {
      name    = "Rule-${rule.key}"
      enabled = true
      filters {
        prefix_match = [rule.value]
        blob_types   = ["blockBlob"]
      }
      actions {
        base_blob {
          delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 15
        }
        snapshot {
          delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = 15
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Hello @Marko E,
Hope you are doing well
I updated my code with your code. I am getting below error with your code -
Inappropriate value for attribute "prefix_match": set of string required.

Ah, ok, let me fix that.

Sorry for bothering on Friday. Did you get a chance to look into this error message. Thanks :)

I fixed it yesterday, please try again.

Great, here's how you can accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow/86979#86979.


The lists of more than 30 containers are defined in the input.tfvars file as lists of strings which needs to be called in main.tf in “resource azurerm_storage_management_policy lifecycle”

The lifecycle management policy to multiple containers specified in the containername variable, you’ll need to iterate over each container name and create a separate rule for each one.
Here is the updated Terraform code to create a lifecycle management policy for all the containers in the storage account.
terraform.tfvars
 containername  =  ["venkat1", "venkat2", "venkat3", "venkat4", "venkat5", "v6enkat","venkat7","venkat8","venkat9","venkat10","venkat11","venkat12","venkat13","venkat14","venkat15","venkat16","venkat17","venkat18","venkat19","venkat20","venkat21","venkat22","venkat23","venkat24","venkat25"]


variables.tf
    variable "containername" {
      type    = list(string)
      default = []
    }


storage.tf
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
      name                = "demostoracc2304"
      resource_group_name = "Sri"
    }
    
    locals {
      folderlist1 = var.containername
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_management_policy" "lifecycle" {
      storage_account_id = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    
      dynamic "rule" {
        for_each = range(length(local.folderlist1))
    
        content {
          name    = "Rule-${rule.key + 1}"
          enabled = true
    
          filters {
            prefix_match = [local.folderlist1[rule.key]]
            blob_types   = ["blockBlob"]
          }
    
          actions {
            base_blob {
              delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 15
            }
            snapshot {
              delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = 15
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    output "result1" {
      value = local.folderlist1
    }


Output:

After running the script, rules are created in the management policy of the storage account for all containers specified in variables.tf.

